# How to sort data both 'horizontally' and 'vertically' with SQL?

Tags: sql

a sample table:

```
+------+--------+---------+
|  id  |  type  |  date   |
+------+--------+---------+
|    1 |    A   | 201205  |
|    2 |    A   | 201206  |
|    3 |    A   | 201206  |
|    4 |    A   | 201207  |
|    5 |    B   | 201205  |
|    6 |    B   | 201206  |
|    7 |    C   | 201206  |
|    8 |    C   | 201206  |
+------+--------+---------+
```

the goal: to show the amount of each type every month:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|      | 201205 | 201206 | 201207 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|  A   |    1   |    2   |   1    |
|  B   |    1   |    1   |   0    |
|  C   |    0   |    2   |   0    |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

There are many months in the actual table, how to write the sql without laboriously using join?

I used multiple join to do this, the sql started to be very long and I had to use another language to dynamically generate it.

```
SELECT type ``, a.201205, b.201206, c.201207 FROM
(SELECT type FROM t GROUP BY type) foo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT count(id) `201205` ,type FROM t WHERE date = '201205' GROUP BY type) a
USING (type)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT count(id) `201206` ,type FROM t WHERE date = '201206' GROUP BY type) b
USING (type)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT count(id) `201207` ,type FROM t WHERE date = '201207' GROUP BY type) c
USING (type)
```

PS: I can't find a proper title for my post, please help me change it.

Comment: do a search for "pivot" and "sql"

Comment: @Glenn:thanks, it's very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

This won't output exactly in the format you're looking for but will display "the amount of each type every month":

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, type, COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM table GROUP BY date, type
```